# No driver for Intel integrated graphics, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, laptop, intel-graphics

I bought a laptop "Lenovo ThinkBook 14+" recently. This is a newly released machine version. Its original OS is Windows 11 and I freshly install a Ubuntu 22.04 on it. However, it seems that there is no available driver for my laptop's integrated graphics in linux distro. The CPU is Intel Core Ultra 5 125H, which was released just several months ago.

Now it's using the `llvmpipe` for graphics. I can't change the resolution and fresh rate of the "Unknown Display". My question is that is it my only choice to wait for a higher version of Ubuntu, e.g., 24.04? If so, is there any harm for my laptop to keep using the llvmpipe for graphics?

Machine config:

[image: machine config]

[output of `cpufetch`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDPbb.jpg)

Comment: Can you install `cpufetch` with `sudo apt install cpufetch`, run the command `cpufetch`, and post the output?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems temporally resolved by a method called "force probe", details in [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2495988).

[Yellow Pasque](https://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=327594) provided [this answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2495988&p=14182328#post14182328):

> ```
> echo "options i915 force_probe=7d55" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf
> ```
>
> Reboot. Keep in mind that this isn't "officially stable" according to Intel, so if you have issues, revert the change (by deleting the file you created) and reboot.
>
> ```
> sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf
> ```

Comment: nice work! It would be great to get an update here if you find that 24.04 fixes it properly

Answer (score 0):

First, install intel graphics driver by

```
sudo apt install -y gpg-agent wget
wget -qO - https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/intel-graphics.key |
  sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository \
  'deb [arch=amd64] https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal main'
```

Then, add the graphics software packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install \
  intel-opencl-icd \
  intel-level-zero-gpu level-zero \
  intel-media-va-driver-non-free libmfx1
```

Finally, install development packages:

```
sudo apt install \
  libigc-dev \
  intel-igc-cm \
  libigdfcl-dev \
  libigfxcmrt-dev \
  level-zero-dev
```

For more details, refer to this link: https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/install-intel-graphic-drivers